# agent.goToPopulation not working when entering a Queue using AnyLogic

Tags: anylogic

I was hoping to be able to use the On Enter action of a queue, to add the agent to a specific population using:

```
agent.goToPopulation(expeditedCases);
```

[image]

However at run time, I see the queue getting filled, but no agents entering any of the agent collections?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you are running your model so far is purely DES, so your agents are not part of any population which is why the function you used is not working. Instead, do the following at the source:

[image]

Of course, instead of A, use the needed agent type.

Comment: Thanks, but still not working.  I set this to adverseEvents population, sill all populations are empty at runtime.

Comment: Yes, this is expected because you only have queues and a sink in the end. So a queue does not delay the agent any second. Instantaneously, the agent is going from source to sink. Once an agent enters the sink, it is disposed of and no longer exists (thus empty population). To solve it, use "Exit" block instead of "Sink".

Comment: ah, thanks.  Any tips on the best way to remove X number of agents from the queue per day?

Comment: You could use a cyclic event with a recurrence time of 1 day. In the action field of the event use a for loop with a number of cycles equal to the number of agents you want to remove and the code in the body would need to use the function "remove(0)" So you write:

queue.remove(0). 0 is good to use because you'll keep removing the first one in the queue. Make sure to add a condition that this should be executed only if queue size is greater than 0 so if( queue.size() > 0) otherwise you'll have an error.

Comment: Thanks.  I need to prioritize the queue but by a number of variables the agents  - how close they are to reaching 15 days since creation, and the seriousness

Comment: These are becoming too many questions different from the initial question... It is not easy to answer them in comments.

Comment: I know, can't blame a man for trying .   I will create a new question on queue prioritisation if I can't work it out.  Thanks!

Comment: If this one is answered, you can mark it as such and move to another one for better results, yes.

Comment: Thanks, maybe add something to your answer to elaborate on the fact that if I want to see the results, I need to make sure things don't go immediately into the sink.  I did have a delay built in but it was 1 second.  I changed it to days and started to see a build up in the collections.

Comment: "The way you are running your model so far is purely DES, so your agents are not part of any population which is why the function you used is not working". This is not true and using the custom population is not needed; see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach does work but, because you have nothing to hold your agents after the queues, they immediately enter the `Sink`, at which point they are removed from the population they are part of.

By default, a `Source` block adds agents to a hidden default population (and you can move it to another population from there fine): you can access it via `getDefaultPopulation()`. You could instead get the Source block to add them to a defined custom population if you need not-yet-assigned-to-a-queue agents to also exist in a specifically-named population.

**However**, this use of agent populations isn't the normal approach in a 'pure' process model like this. You have access to the agents inside each Queue anyway (via the Queue's `agents` function) if you needed that. And, for example, this might also/instead be something you wanted to show visually via the agents' animations (e.g., with different colours depending on the queue/state they were in). That requires use of space markup (or assigning coordinates to agents) so as to make them exist somewhere spatially whilst they move through the process flow.

Comment: Thanks.  I was using collections to periodically gather stats, as per the AnyLogic in 3 days example.

Comment: Ah yes that is one benefit: having access to statistics on populations. (Though you can also just calculate statistics 'manually' using Java in an AnyLogic function: a count population statistic, for example, is just looping through the agents inside, counting those where the condition is true which boils down to 3 or 4 lines of Java; the population statistic still requires you to write the core Java expression, but does the loop and count accumulation for you.)